# GKE Pod Connect to external VM in same subnet

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I Have a pod that needs to connect to a Database located on GCE Vm's with the same subnet as the GKE nodes. I currently have a k8 Service and k8 Endpoint that the pod successfully connects to but the 10.128.0.2 cannot be routed. Im sure this pertains to a GCP firewall rule/route but I havn't had much luck.

subnet -> 10.128.0.0/9

cbr0 -> 10.8.15.0/20

eth0 -> 10.128.0.1

k8 services -> 10.11.224/14

Master Version: 1.9.7-gke.3

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: externalDB
  namespace: default
 subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.128.0.2 
    ports:
      - port: 7199 
        name: interface
```

"

Comment: Hi, why are you using endpoints? Are you trying to load balance the external db? If not then just go directly from the pod... no need for the extra hop .

Comment: You're right that the endpoint isn't required. It's basically being used to provide a dns entry for the external service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point in time, services and endpoints are not routable; however pods are as explained in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/prep-kubernetes-engine-for-prod#communicating_within_the_same_cluster). As @cohenjo mentioned, you should directly connect from the pod.

Edit: I believe that this issue is due to a firewall change on Clusters that are running 1.9.x as described in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#autofirewall). You can follow the steps provided in the article to allow communication from the GKE cluster to all VM instances on the network or attach the network tag assigned on the node to the VM instance you would like the pod to communicate with.

Comment: When I use the address in the pod (10.128.0.2) I still get the same issue where the host is unreachable

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue by creating a cluster using the same version. I created a pod within the cluster. I then went into one of my GCE VM instances and pinged the pod IP from the instance. I was successfully able to ping the Pod IP. Can you try pinging the Pod IP from the VM instance and let me know if it is successful?

Comment: Yes, the pings from 10.128.0.2 (GCE VM) are successful against the pod ( 10.8.25.3 ). however from the pod I cannot connect to 10.128.0.2

Comment: Alright, thank you for that update. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, following the article to add the firewall rule that was in 1.8.x worked.

Comment: Thanks, really: I was becoming crazy with this problem. The article give easy steps to solve it